# Class constructor - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, oop, dataframe, genetic-algorithm

This code snippet is part of a much larger genetic algorithm. When I run it I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` for the line `agent.buy = agent.buy[i] + random.randint(0, in_prices_length)`.

I realize you can't take an index on a plain integer value, but I'm confused because the self.buy within the Agent class is initialized as a list. I don't work with object oriented python much, so I'm sure I'm glossing over something simple, I just can't find it.

```
class Agent:

    def __init__(self, length):

        self.buy = [random.randint(0,length), random.randint(0,length)]
        self.fitness = -1

in_prices = None
in_prices_length = None
population = 20
generations = 100

def ga():

    agents = init_agents(population, in_prices_length)

    for generation in range(generations):

        print ('Generation: ' + str(generation))

        agents = fitness(agents)
        agents = selection(agents)
        agents = crossover(agents)
        agents = mutate(agents)

def init_agents(population, length):

    return [Agent(length) for _ in range(population)]

def mutate(agents):

    for agent in agents:

        for i in range(2):

            if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) <= 0.1:

                agent.buy = agent.buy[i] + random.randint(0, in_prices_length)

    return agents

if __name__ == '__main__':


    raw = pd.read_csv('IBM.csv')
    in_prices = raw['close'].tolist()
    in_prices = list(reversed(in_prices))[0:300]
    in_prices_length = len(in_prices)
    ga()
```

Comment: `agent.buy` might be initialized as a list, but when you do this you assign a single number to it: `agent.buy = agent.buy[i] + random.randint(0, in_prices_length)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Gotcha! That line was originally for adding strings together so it makes sense that it wouldn't work the same for lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `mutate()`, agent.buy is defined as the sum of two integers.

In addition, it would depend on the source data in your csv file that is assigned 
to the value 'raw'.

Comment: Ahh, okay I see. So instead it should probably be like this `agent.buy = agent.buy[i, random.randint(0, in_prices_length)]`

Comment: Hmm...I tried the correction I commented above but it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

But it is not a list **always**, as per your code. You iterate through the range (0..1), and reset the `agent.buy` value in the first iteration to an integer. In the second iteration, you again try to access the `buy` as a list, but it is set to an integer in the previous iteration.

I suspect you want to do:

```
agent.buy[i] = agent.buy[i] + random.randint(0, in_prices_length)
```

But I'm not sure without knowing the algorithm :) .

Comment: Okay, that totally makes sense. The tutorial I was working off of was concatenating a string with this line of code, and when I changed it to a list/integer it obviously doesn't work the same. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Update: I tried your recommendation but it still returns the same error.